# Translating ?x style pattern variables to optima

Tags: pattern-matching, common-lisp

What's in the equivalent, in [optima](https://github.com/m2ym/optima), of these two pattern matching examples - from On Lisp and PAIP, respectively?

```
>(match ’(p a b c a) ’(p ?x ?y c ?x))
((?Y . B) (?X . A))
T


(difference between ?x* and ?y*)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The patterns in optima look as if they are building the form you are matching.  So for example in this simple example:

```
(ql:quickload "optima")
(defpackage #:example (:use #:common-lisp #:optima))
(in-package #:example)
(match '(a b c) ((list 'a 'b X) (print X)))
```

The pattern is the form `(list 'a 'b x)` and that last form will print: `c`

Where as `(match '(a b c d) ((list* 'a 'b  x) (print x)))` will print: `(c d)`

You maybe familiar with the sweet special syntax for building lists known as backquote.  It is often used in defining macros were lots of s-expresssions are constructed.  There is a add on package for optima that lets you write your patterns in the same manner.

```
(ql:quickload '("fare-quasiquote-optima" "fare-quasiquote-readtable"))
(named-readtables:in-readtable :fare-quasiquote)

(match '(a b c) (`(a b ,x) x))
(match '(a b c) (`(a b ,@x) x))
```

Those last two forms will return `c` and `(c)` respectively.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks for the `fare-quasiquote-optima` examples! By the way, I found the first examples more meaningful than the "sweetened" ones, in that the latter lost the semantic value of `list` and `list*`.